# How to target all browsers with Gulp auto-prefixer

Tags: javascript, browser, gulp, build-system, gulp-autoprefixer

I am very new to Gulp and have never used any plugins before so I'm a bit lost.

I have followed some tutorials and just about managed to get Gulp running and the auto-prefixer plugin. I am now just trying to work out if there is a way to get it it prefix for all versions of all browsers?

On [this browser list](https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries), I can select things like the last 2 versions of all major browsers, or a range of versions, but I would like to select all versions of all browsers (major and other). I am especially trying to add support for the default **Samsung** browser, as I am having some browser compatibility issues with that at the moment and am hoping some prefixes could be the solution.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('prefix', function () {
    gulp.src('css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['prefix']);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the Samsung browser just android mobile?

Comment: @Barryman9000 Nope. It's a tablet - Samsung Galaxy 8.0, Android version 4.4.2, browser version 4.4.2

Comment: It seems strange that a newer Samsung browser wouldn't fall under the "modern browsers" level of support. You can try visiting https://html5test.com/ to see what's lacking

Comment: Oh... I guess android 4.4 is older. My bad

Answer (score 5):

You can find a list of all the prefix options here. I'm not sure there's anything to target a Samsung browser specifically

https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries

So an example autoprefixer task might look like this

```
let autoprefixBrowsers = ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'firefox >= 4', 'safari 7', 'safari 8', 'IE 8', 'IE 9', 'IE 10', 'IE 11'];

gulp.task('prefix', function () {
    gulp.src('css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(prefix({ browsers: autoprefixBrowsers }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```